# "can simply select" vs "can select simply"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, sentence-construction

I would like to understand the correct way to use the words **simply** or **easily** in my sentence.

For example,

**After the verb, directly:**

> Method A can simply estimate the correct parameters.
>
> Method A can easily estimate the correct parameters.

**Or, at the end of the sentence:**

> Method A can estimate the correct parameters, simply.
>
> Method A can estimate the correct parameters, easily.

What is the correct usage of these two words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "after the verb" sentences flow more naturally than your "end of sentence" sentences, and your "after the verb" sentences are more similar to the sentences found in textbooks and academic works.

The "end of sentence" sentences are not necessarily grammatically incorrect; they just are less likely to be used.